# Is there a way to shorten my if-elif-else statement in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am reading in data from a csv file and doing a larger loop that each time it goes through counts num_2 += 1. Each time it goes through, I want it to add all the data from that round and then median it. However, I need to do this with ~50 objects (~50 if-elif-else statements), is there a way to shorten it down more/make it more efficient?

```
                    if num_2 == 1:
                        #mag
                        test1_flux.append(mag_flux)
                        median1_flux = np.median(test1_flux)
                        test1_ap.append(mag_ap)
                        median1_ap = np.median(test1_ap)
                        #err
                        test1_flux_err.append(mag_flux)
                        std1_flux = np.std(test1_flux_err)
                        test1_ap_err.append(mag_flux)
                        std1_ap = np.std(test1_ap_err)
                    elif num_2 == 2:
                        test2_flux.append(mag_flux)
                        median2_flux = np.median(test2_flux)
                        test2_ap.append(mag_ap)
                        median2_ap = np.median(test2_ap)
                        #err
                        test2_flux_err.append(mag_flux)
                        std2_flux = np.std(test2_flux_err)
                        test2_ap_err.append(mag_flux)
                        std2_ap = np.std(test2_ap_err)
                    elif num_2 == 3:
                        test3_flux.append(mag_flux)
                        median3_flux = np.median(test3_flux)
                        test3_ap.append(mag_ap)
                        median3_ap = np.median(test3_ap)
                        #err
                        test3_flux_err.append(mag_flux)
                        std3_flux = np.std(test3_flux_err)
                        test3_ap_err.append(mag_flux)
                        std3_ap = np.std(test3_ap_err)
                    elif num_2 == 4:
                        test4_flux.append(mag_flux)
                        median4_flux = np.median(test4_flux)
                        test4_ap.append(mag_ap)
                        median4_ap = np.median(test4_ap)
                        #err
                        test4_flux_err.append(mag_flux)
                        std4_flux = np.std(test4_flux_err)
                        test4_ap_err.append(mag_flux)
                        std4_ap = np.std(test4_ap_err)
                    elif num_2 == 5:
                        test5_flux.append(mag_flux)
                        median5_flux = np.median(test5_flux)
                        test5_ap.append(mag_ap)
                        median5_ap = np.median(test5_ap)
                        #err
                        test5_flux_err.append(mag_flux)
                        std5_flux = np.std(test5_flux_err)
                        test5_ap_err.append(mag_flux)
                        std5_ap = np.std(test5_ap_err)
                    elif num_2 == 6:
                        test6_flux.append(mag_flux)
                        median6_flux = np.median(test6_flux)
                        test6_ap.append(mag_ap)
                        median6_ap = np.median(test6_ap)
                        #err
                        test6_flux_err.append(mag_flux)
                        std6_flux = np.std(test6_flux_err)
                        test6_ap_err.append(mag_flux)
                        std6_ap = np.std(test6_ap_err)
                    elif num_2 == 7:
                        test7_flux.append(mag_flux)
                        median7_flux = np.median(test7_flux)
                        test7_ap.append(mag_ap)
                        median7_ap = np.median(test7_ap)
                        #err
                        test7_flux_err.append(mag_flux)
                        std7_flux = np.std(test7_flux_err)
                        test7_ap_err.append(mag_flux)
                        std7_ap = np.std(test7_ap_err)
                    else:
                        pass
```

Comment: If you have explicitly-numbered variable names, you should be using a `list` and index it instead, and probably a class to collect the different lists being tracked for each object.

Comment: Try using a common method to run all the operations since all the methods have the same name between objects. Together with Mark's suggestion, you can run the methods by passing the required object from the list of objects to the common method.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is using map/dictionary to store results instead of large set of variables an option?